# UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString wrap tag with other tag

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

Let's say I have an HTML like this:

```
<html>
<form>
<input type="button"  id="Signature8"  pdfFieldName="Signature8"  onclick="document.location='pdz://signatureTapped?name=Signature8'" />
</form>
</html>
```

and I want to replace it programmatically with

```
<html>
<form>
<img src="Signature8.png">
<input type="button"  id="Signature8"  pdfFieldName="Signature8"  onclick="document.location='pdz://signatureTapped?name=Signature8'" />
</img>
</form>
</html>
```

in Objective-C with a UIWebView. What I did so far, is come up with this:

```
-(void) injectCode:(NSString*) code intoWebView:(UIWebView*) webView withEndCode:(NSString*) endCode {
  NSString* innerhtml = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.forms[0].%@.outerHTML", self.identifier]];
  NSString* newCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.forms[0].%@.outerHTML=%@%@%@", self.identifier, code, innerhtml, endCode];
  [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:newCode];
  NSLog(@"%@", [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.outerHTML"]);
}
```

which should be called like this:

```
  [f injectCode:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src=\"%@.png\" id=\"%@\">", f.identifier, f.identifier] intoWebView:self.webView withEndCode:@"</img>"];
```

(whereas f is an object that contains the name, identifier, etc. of that Signature8 field).
The problem is: this doesn't work. When I debug through it, I can see innerhtml filled, I can see that newCode is actually correct (to me at least) and I thought that the line that assigns outerHTML with newCode and all that should replace the whole HTML accordingly. To verify, I logged it out to the console. Yeah.. nothing changed at all.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I cannot use jQuery or any other framework really, as the code should get its HTML forms from third parties and they do not have to use jQuery or anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well unfortunately not, but I found a solution with a proxy that can modify the HTML on the fly before I get it. Works as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the quotes around the new html:

```
NSString* newCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.forms[0].%@.outerHTML=\"%@%@%@\";", self.identifier, code, innerhtml, endCode];
```

Remember outerHTML is expecting a string.